# Prove that $\operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(B)=\operatorname{rank}(A,B)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have problem with following problem:

Let $A,B \in M_{m\times n}$ and $B^TA=0$ show that rank A+rankB=rank(A,B) where $(A,B)$ is a matrix created by adding to matrix A matrix B to the right side

I don't know what clue I need to obtain from $B^TA=0$

Comment: Important caveat: The matrices must have real entries in order for this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$B^TA=0$ just tells you that the columns of $B$ and $A$ are linearly indepedent. So the matrix $(A,B)$ has $rank A+rankB$ lineraly indepedent columns.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can justify it correctly from $B^TA=0$ we have that $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i\cdot c'_i=0$ where $c_i$ are columns in $B$ and $c'_i$ columns in $A$ but is it sufficient ?

Comment: $B^T A = 0$ shows that each column of $A$ is orthogonal to each column of $B$. Over the reals, two orthogonal subspaces are linearly disjoint.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** note that each entry of $B^TA$ is the dot product of a column from $B$ and a column from $A$.